# I have a customer table and want to find duplicate entries from submission table and show it in customer table in new field

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a customer table and want to find duplicate entries from submission table and show it in customer table in new field (like in final table)

Customer table

`id  email
 1   abc@gmail.com
 3   xyz@gmail.com
 4   ymz@gmail.com`

Submission table

```
id  Submitteduser
1   abc@gmail.com
2   abc@gmail.com
3   xyz@gmail.com
4   ymz@gmail.com
```

Final table

```
id  email          count
1   abc@gmail.com    2
3   xyz@gmail.com    1
4   ymz@gmail.com    1
```

help me to make this query

Comment: what you mean by duplicate entry in your case ? is it duplicate emaild's ? If you take entire record, they are not duplicates

Comment: yes i mean duplicate emails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query: [Click Here For Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/953c4b/14/0)

```
SELECT a.id, a.email, COUNT(b.Submitteduser)  FROM Customer AS a
JOIN Submission AS b 
ON a.email = b.Submitteduser
GROUP BY b.Submitteduser
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following query

```
select Submission.id, Customer.email, count(Customer.*) from Customer inner join Submission on (email = Submitteduser) group by Submission.Submitteduser
```